# Highcharts: Add circle to scatter plot

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to draw a circle on a scatter plot to highlight values outside of the acceptable range.

I tried to use chart.renderer.circle but that uses the x and y pixels of the SVG element. I still want to be able to zoom in or out, so absolute x and y values don't work.

Is this possible with Highchart?

**Edit:**
Added Mockup:

[image: scatter plot with circle]

Comment: Could you attach mockup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ideas...

**ONE**

Use `chart.renderer.circle` and translate the point values to pixels.

Say you want to draw a circle at:

```
var circleX = 161.2;  // x coordinate
var circleY = 51.6; // y coordinate
var circleR = 1.0;  // radius size in terms of x axis distance
```

Draw the circle as:

```
function addCircle(chart){
    if (this.circle){
        // on a redraw, remove old circle
        $(this.circle.element).remove();
    }

    // translate my coordinates to pixel values
    var pixelX = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(circleX);
    var pixelY = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(circleY);
    var pixelR = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(circleR) - chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(0);        

    // add my circle
    this.circle = chart.renderer.circle(pixelX, pixelY, pixelR).attr({
        fill: 'transparent',
        stroke: 'black',
        'stroke-width': 1
        });
    this.circle.add();        
}
```

You then call this in the load and redraw events and all is awesome:

```
        events: {
            load: function(){
               addCircle(this); 
            },
            redraw: function(){
               addCircle(this);
            }
        }
```

Here's a fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/K8FbQ/).

**TWO**

Add the circle as another series, make the marker a giant transparent circle:

```
    {
        data: [[circleX, circleY]],
        linkedTo: 'other', // link it to other series to avoid legend entry
        marker: {
            radius: 40,
            lineColor: 'red',
            fillColor: 'transparent',
            lineWidth: 1,
            symbol: 'circle'
        }
    }
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xtVEg/) for this one.

Comment: Thank you! I used the first option.